# Can win8.1 system image backup files be relocated to USB drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, windows-8.1, backup, system-restore

As per http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/what-happened-to-backup-restore, I tried twice to backup my win8.1 to my USB 3.0 WD Ultra My Passport 1TB Drive; both times the backup failed.

For that reason, I backed up to another partition on the same physical hard disk.

As per the warning from System image backup, I realize that the backup will be useless should the physical hard disk fail.

Can I safely copy the files from my backup partition on my physical hard drive to the USB drive manually?

If yes, which files should I copy?

```
L:\   
<DIR>          System Volume Information
<DIR>          WindowsImageBackup

L:\WindowsImageBackup\gerryLowry
<DIR>          Backup 2015-02-03 003812
<DIR>          Catalog
<DIR>          Logs
<DIR>          SPPMetadataCache
            16 MediaId

L:\WindowsImageBackup\gerryLowry\Backup 2015-02-03 003812
    383,778,816 19aa7f2f-6027-45c4-9853-21e48f2f9cc9.vhdx
            776 7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61_AdditionalFilesc3b9f3c7-5e52-4d5e-8b20-19adc95a34c7.xml
         29,442 7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61_Components.xml
          8,196 7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61_RegistryExcludes.xml
         31,434 7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61_Writer4dc3bdd4-ab48-4d07-adb0-3bee2926fd7f.xml
          1,488 7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61_Writer542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f.xml
          1,484 7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61_Writera6ad56c2-b509-4e6c-bb19-49d8f43532f0.xml
          3,828 7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61_Writerafbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485.xml
         11,022 7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61_Writerbe000cbe-11fe-4426-9c58-531aa6355fc4.xml
          5,902 7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61_Writercd3f2362-8bef-46c7-9181-d62844cdc0b2.xml
      5,152,496 7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61_Writere8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220.xml
          1,528 BackupSpecs.xml
106,304,634,880 ce7669e1-4e6d-40e7-aabb-e4230bff7c0d.vhdx
    278,921,216 Esp.vhdx

L:\WindowsImageBackup\gerryLowry\Catalog
         7,560 BackupGlobalCatalog
        10,946 GlobalCatalog

L:\WindowsImageBackup\gerryLowry\Logs
             4 Backup_Error-03-02-2015_00-38-12.log

L:\WindowsImageBackup\gerryLowry\SPPMetadataCache
       122,080 {7888e0e6-487c-457c-a26f-df0b93a35c61}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should copy the entire *WindowsImageBackup* folder to another drive. Keep in mind that this folder must not be NTFS-compressed or encrypted when you are trying to restore from it.

Test steps:

1. Created a system recovery image of C drive and saved to a hard disk D:
2. Ran `XCOPY D:\WindowsImageBackup E:\WindowsImageBackup /S /E` [as SYSTEM user](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/10/22/getting-a-cmd-prompt-as-system-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008.aspx). (E: is yet another hard disk)
3. Unplugged C drive and D drive, i.e. I disconnected my Windows boot drive and the drive where I originally backed up to. Now I only had the disk with a copied WindowsImageBackup folder
4. Plugged in yet another blank hard disk so I could restore Windows onto it.
5. Rebooted to Windows 8.1 setup DVD, and chose recovery, troubleshoot, ..., System Image Recovery
6. It was able to fully restore the Windows installation without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an image file (.iso) you can just manually copy it to the external HDD. If you have a partition that you want to copy you can create and image file of this partition and place it on the external HDD. ( Since you have a WD drive you can use a free copy of Acronis True Image WD edition)

Comment: thnx for your input; i've added the file list that gets created above; no .iso file is created; for that reason, i'm wondering whether i can successfully *copy* the entire *WindowsImageBackup* directory and it will simply work from the USB drive for restoring my system; i.e., if i *copy* it, will i break it?